# Android SoundPool.stop does not seem to work

Tags: android, soundpool

I have created a class MySoundPool (I am using this class as sigelton, but don't think this is relevant as everyting else works). I am initianalizing SoundPool, a HashMap, and get the context for AudioManager. Thereafter I am loading two sounds.
MySoundpool is used by method MySoundPool.playSound(int index, float rate)
playSound clips rate to 0.5 <= rate >= 2.0 an executes statements

```
float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, index, 0, rate);
```

So far so good. Everything works fine.
No it happens that playSound is called while the previous sound still plays, and I want to stop that before playing the new sound. Prior to the above code snippet I tried

```
mSoundPool.stop(mSoundPoolMap.get(index));
```

and

```
mSoundPool.autoPause();
```

with no success. The sound just continues to play to its end.
Any comments will be appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume that you create a new SoundPool object in the constructor of your MySoundPool class?

If so then the first argument that SoundPool's constructor takes is the number of streams to allow at the same time. for example...

```
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

That will allow 10 sounds to play at once so just change the 10 to a 1 and that should do it.

Edit:
The stop() method takes a stream id as an argument, which should be the number returned from the play() method. You could try setting a variable equal to what play() returns and then use that variable when stopping the sound.

Comment: What a ploy! Doesn't make SoundPool.stop() working, but it serves my needs. Perfect and thanks much for the fast answer, Kieran!

Comment: No problem, and yea this is kind of a workaround but I just realized I didn't really answer your question, but instead gave a workaround. Look at my edits above to see how to get stop to work I believe It's because you gave stop() the wrong argument...

Comment: Indeed! It's not the mSoundPoolMap.get(index), but the streamID returned by the call of mSoundPool.play(...)
Thanks again, you saved my day

Answer (score 11):

Use the soundId to play a sound but use the streamId to stop it. These are not always the same number!

When you start the sound, store the returned streamId:

```
int myStreamId = mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, index, 0, rate);
```

Then use that streamId (not the soundId) to stop the sound:

```
mSoundPool.stop(myStreamId);
```

Comment: If I could tell how many times I read the doc and took for granted that the `streamID` and `soundID` were the same.
This is the right answer!!

Comment: You save my day. Who could even think, that method `play()` returns another `streamId`, that should be used further.

Comment: Thanks! This should have been selected as the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the class document:

public final int play (int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)
Since: API Level 1

Play a sound from a sound ID. Play the sound specified by the soundID. This is the value returned by the load() function. Returns a non-zero streamID if successful, zero if it fails. The streamID can be used to further control playback.

Returns

```
non-zero streamID if successful, zero if failed
```

Had the same problem, why does one not read the F M ! :D

-Thanks guys!